# Regex to replace all but the last non-breaking space if multiple words are joined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Using javascript (including jQuery), I’m trying to replace all but the last non-breaking space if multiple words are joined.

For example:

Replace `A&#160;String&#160;of&#160;Words` with `A String of&#160;Words`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
> "A&#160;String&#160;of&#160;Words".replace(/&#160;(?=.*?&#160;)/g, " ")
'A String of&#160;Words'
```

The above regex would match all the `&#160;` strings except the last one.

Comment: Nice.  If you use this, it might be worth adding a comment that the `.*?&#160;` has the lazy qualifier so it's O(n) instead of O(n²).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is like this, you can use [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) to do this.

```
var r = 'A&#160;String&#160;of&#160;Words'.replace(/&#160;(?![^&]*$)/g, ' ');
//=> "A String of&#160;Words"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to regex, easier to understand:

```
var fn = function(input, sep) {
    var parts = input.split(sep);
    var last = parts.pop();
    return parts.join(" ") + sep + last;
};

> fn("A&#160;String&#160;of&#160;Words", "&#160;")
"A String of&#160;Words"
```

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Don't what?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown `Using javascript (including jQuery), I’m trying to replace all but the last non-breaking space if multiple words are joined.` As far as I see his only interested in the result. But even if he isn't that's an alternative solution and definitely does not deserve -1.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Please read one more time everything I've just written. I'll point out the crucial word to you: "alternative". It's getting boring.